# Rails 4 generates an empty manifest.json file when I run RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline, precompile

On my staging server, I am having some troubles.

When I run

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Then

```
ls public/assets/
```

> ```
> manifest-e694d7a3911e13a1b7c31ee3a73ccc9d.json>
> ```

Then

> $ cat public/assets/manifest-e694d7a3911e13a1b7c31ee3a73ccc9d.json
>
> {}

However, if I just run rake assets:precompile (without the RAILS_ENV=production flag), then I get a bunch of CSS and JS, as well as my images, put into the public/assets folder.  Unfortunately, however, there are two problems:

1) The fingerprint (the md5 hash ) on the .js and .css files doesn't match what javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_link_tag automatically spit out

2) Inside the generated CSS file, I see references to my static asset, but they don't include the md5 hash fingerprint, even though I explicitly ask for it; e.g.

> ```
> background-image: url(image-path('home/logo.png'));
> ```

It just generates

> ```
> background-image: url("/assets/home/logo.png");
> ```

Even though the file that gets generated is,

> logo-a412c0ad6a034e4da4324436fff2f871.png

The relevant (I think) bits of the appropriate files:

Here is my application.rb

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Here is my development.rb

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

Here is my production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.precompile = true
```

Here is my nginx conf

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  staging.mysite.com;

  root /var/www/myuser/current/public;

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
      root   html;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://appname; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
    root /var/www/myuser/current/public;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }


}
```

Thank you for your help.  I have been banging my head here for a while now.  Please let me know if I should share more information.

Comment: When I remove the config.assets.precompile = true line (I'm not sure how that got in there), the appropriate assets are compiled and the correct CSS and JS assets are linked to from the app.  However, *within the CSS*, the images are not linked to with the fingerprints.  the home/logo.png problem (instead of home/logo-hash.png) persists..

Comment: New update:  If I run RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile on the server directly, it then spits out the CSS with the right fingerprints.  But the CSS and js filename fingerprints don't match the fingerprint spit out by image_tag and link_tag.  So I am precompiling the assets locally, checking them into git, and then uploading to production.. Not an elegant solution

Comment: config.assets.compile = true means you have live compilation on production server. Usually it is false.